# How to find the script src link?(Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
tags = [{tag.name: tag.text.strip()} for tag in soup.find_all('h2')]
```

This returns as:

```
[{'h2':'My'},{'h2':'hey'}] # Returns all the h2 elements with their content.
```

Now I want all the links that are inside the `<script src =''>`  in the above format.

Suppose, For the HTML code,

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.hvE_rrhCzPE.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AHpOoo-98F2Gk-siNaIBZOtcWfXQWKdTpQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0" nonce="" async=""></script>
```

The result should be

```
#Both Acceptable

[{'script':'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.hvE_rrhCzPE.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AHpOoo-98F2Gk-siNaIBZOtcWfXQWKdTpQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0'}]

OR

[{'script src':'https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.hvE_rrhCzPE.O/m=gapi_iframes,googleapis_client/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AHpOoo-98F2Gk-siNaIBZOtcWfXQWKdTpQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the tag you are finding from `h2` to `script`. Then instead of getting the text of that element with `tag.text`, you are wanting the attribute value in the syntax of `tag['attribute name']`. So something like:

```
tags = [{tag.name: tag['src']} for tag in soup.find_all('script')]
```